# Hide content based on set cookie

Tags: jquery, cookies

I'm setting myCookie for specific domain and when the cookie is set I want to hide content, but the show/hide IF statement is not working at all.

I would like to use the jquery .cookie plug-in, but this is what i have so far. writing the cookie does work, i just can't get the hide to function properly.

```
var cookieName = 'myCookie';
var cookieValue = 'myCookie';
var myDate = new Date();
myDate.setMonth(myDate.getMonth() + 12);
document.cookie = cookieName +"=" + cookieValue + ";expires=" + myDate 
                  + ";domain=.example.com;path=/";

$(document).ready(function(){
    if ($.cookieName('myCookie') >= 0) {
        $('.myContent').hide();
    }
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="myContent">
hide this content if the cookie is set
</div>
otherwise show this content if you don't have the required cookie
```

Any help in this would be much appreciated!

Comment: are you using any jQuery cookie plugin? otherwise this `$.cookieName` may trow an error or be undefined

Comment: I'm not, but I would like to... just trying to get this to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made you an example:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$.cookie('myCookie', 25);

$(document).ready(function(){

    if ($.cookie('myCookie') >= 0) {
        $('.myContent').hide();
    }
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="myContent">
hide this content if the cookie is set
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This example hide the div because 25 > 0.

In other case:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$.cookie('myCookie', 25);

$(document).ready(function(){

    if ($.cookie('myCookie') >= 26) {
        $('.myContent').hide();
    }
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="myContent">
hide this content if the cookie is set
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now i change the if condition and the div it's showing
myCookie = 25 and it's minor than 26 (so its working in both cases).

------------------------------EDITED----------------------------------

Javascript version:

```
function createCookie(name,value,days) {
if (days) {
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
}
else var expires = "";
document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/"; //replace this line

}

function readCookie(name) {
var nameEQ = name + "=";
var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
    if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
}
return null;
}

function eraseCookie(name) {
createCookie(name,"",-1);
}
```

Javascript create cookie call:

```
createCookie('ppkcookie','testcookie',7)  //name_of_cookie,value,num_days
```

Reading the cookie:

```
var x = readCookie('ppkcookie1')
```

Full explanation here: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html

In the createCookie function:

```
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/"; //replace this line

    //with this one adding domain
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires=" + ";domain=.example.com;path=/";
```

Saludos ;)

Comment: thank you much! that's real nice. by the way, using the example i provided where i set the cookie, how could this same effect be done wihtout using jquery and the plug-in?

Comment: You mean with plain javascript??

Comment: yes, without having to use the plug-in. i was curious what it would look like based on my initial approach

Comment: It's very simple....i'm gonna edit my answer to add the javascript explanation ;)

Comment: i'll play with that -- thank you. i do have one final question, thank you again robert. if i want to set this cookie so it can work across multiple domains, the jquery version you provided, for example hello.example.com and world.example.com, which i have control over, i thought i would just append ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.example.com'); but that's not the solution?

Comment: I mean

$.cookie('myCookie', 25, '.example.com');

Comment: I saw your answer, but was this solution for the jquery version? i wanted to compare my options if at all possible

Comment: its for the javascript version....change that line in the createCookie function :)

Answer (score 1):

First,  download **https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie** and reference in your page.

Then, it's as simply as changing your `if` statement to:

```
if ($.cookie("myCookie") !== undefined)
{
    $(".myContent").hide();
}
```

*If you wanted to, you could use `$.cookie` to set the cookie too; the README.md has examples.*